# Jquery filter as alternative to css's structural pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

UPDATE: sorry my IE 9 was'nt configured well: it should've been set so that it accepts to use ActiveX elements. After I done that it worked very well. Sorry for the perturbation.

Question: I want to change the color of each 3rd table's column.

*Initial DOM*:

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>TD #0</td><td>TD #1</td><td>TD #2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TD #3</td><td>TD #4</td><td>TD #5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TD #6</td><td>TD #7</td><td>TD #8</td></tr>
  </table>
```

*Result DOM*

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>TD #0</td><td>TD #1</td><td>-here my color changed green- TD #2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TD #3</td><td>TD #4</td><td>-here my color changed green- TD #5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TD #6</td><td>TD #7</td><td>-here my color changed green- TD #8</td></tr>
  </table>
```

in order to achieved this, i tried with a CSS-3 pseudo class:

```
$("tr td:nth-child(3)").css("color", "green");
```

it works fine in FF, Chrome .. but failed in IE 9.

What would be the corresponding Jquery filter's expression ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well. First of all change to `$("tr td:nth-child(3)").css("color", "green");` if you want green. Second of all: have you tried in ie8 and ie7? I did and it worked well for me. I cannot imagine that it would not work in ie9...Which version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: @MichalB. yes for "red" to "green" ..  for the Browser I tries with IE 9 as said above. And as for the Jquery's version, I declared it with this following URL: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work in IE.

Comment: OK. and just to make sure you are asking a good question here. What's your aim? Do you want the cells to have a colour of your choice or do you require it to be done dynamically after the page has been loaded?

Comment: @MichalB. after the DOM loaded. not dynamically..

Comment: @MichalB. i alsos worked with safari by the way

Comment: And why don't you just make it in css? Without using javascript? Would you be interested in such solution?

Comment: we all know that css 3 got some shortcomings with some "new" browser's versions,so that some workarounds are needed... just like that

Comment: I still think there's something else at work here.  jQuery would implement `:nth-child` directly, not pass it to a browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: @Alnitak yes I got it !! it was config problem.. as explained in My update.. sorry guys!! I accept nbrooks's answer

Comment: @Alnitak ok , i'll do that, I gave a vote

Comment: @Alnitak: IE9 does support `:nth-child()` natively, so jQuery will automatically pass it over, but only for that version if the selector string is valid CSS. It will use its own implementation otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I didn't realize you were doing this for multiple `tr`s. This is the appropriate solution

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    $(this).children("td:eq(2)").css("color","red");
});
```

The solutions below will only work for the first `tr`.

The jquery selctor returns an array of dom elements, so you can always get an element directly using simple array indexing.

```
var elem = $("tr td")[2];
$(elem).css("color","red");
```

This would also work, since it's native jQuery and doesn't rely on css:

```
$("tr td:eq(2)").css("color", "red");
```

NOTE: Both of these techniques use 0-based indexing

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: @Alnitak see question. he asked for an alternative to that for compatibility

Comment: thank for "children" filters + 1

Comment: @nbrooks he shouldn't need an alternative - jQuery _is_ that compatibility layer!

Comment: @Alnitak _"Because jQuery's implementation of :nth-child(n) is strictly derived from the CSS specification..."_ I don't know if it's IE compatible or not, I don't have IE installed (nor do I want it). The question as asked though says it works in chrome, FF, but not IE -- and asks for a pure jQuery filtering alternative. If there is indeed a compatibility issue, then this should avoid it. Otherwise you're quite right jQuery is intended to provide good cross-browser implementations

Comment: @bolt thanks for the info, I wasn't sure because I know older versions had problems with the pseudo-class selectors. good to know :)